# How to Determine Accounts on Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, twitter, windows-phone-8

I would specifically like to know if a user has added a facebook or twitter account to his or her device. Under settings > email+accounts on my device i have facebook and twitter installed, is there a way to check this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to get that information.

Comment: Any idea if this will be available in WP8.1? I've skimmed over the documentation but didn't see anything of light.

Comment: The WP platform is big on user privacy and security, so I doubt it.